# How to optimize the linear coefficients for numpy arrays in a maximization function?

Tags: optimization, scipy, pulp, maximize

I have to optimize the coefficients for three numpy arrays which maximizes my evaluation function. 
I have a target array called train['target'] and three predictions arrays named array1, array2 and array3.

I want to put the best linear coefficients i.e., x,y,z for these three arrays which will maximize the function

roc_aoc_curve(train['target'], x*array1 + y*array2 +z*array3)

the above function would be maximum when prediction is closer to the target. 
i.e, x*array1 + y*array2 + z*array3 should be closer to train['target'].

The range of x,y,z >=0 and x,y,z <= 1

Basically I am trying to put the weights x,y,z for each of the three arrays which would make the function

x*array1 + y*array2 +z*array3 closer to the  train['target']

Any help in getting this would be appreciated.

I used pulp.LpProblem('Giapetto', pulp.LpMaximize) to do the maximization. It works for normal numbers, integers etc, however failing while trying to do with arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import pulp

# create the LP object, set up as a maximization problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem('Giapetto', pulp.LpMaximize)

# set up decision variables
x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=0)
y = pulp.LpVariable('y', lowBound=0)
z = pulp.LpVariable('z', lowBound=0)

score =  roc_auc_score(train['target'],x*array1+ y*array2 + z*array3)

prob += score

coef = x+y+z

prob += (coef==1)

# solve the LP using the default solver
optimization_result = prob.solve()

# make sure we got an optimal solution
assert optimization_result == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

# display the results
for var in (x, y,z):
    print('Optimal weekly number of {} to produce: {:1.0f}'.format(var.name, var.value()))
```

Getting error at the line

```
score =  roc_auc_score(train['target'],x*array1+ y*array2 + z*array3)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'LpVariable'

Can't progress beyond this line when using arrays. Not sure if my approach is correct. Any help in optimizing the function would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a numpy question, this is a pulp question.

Comment: made the change. thanks

Comment: The code is incomplete and does not allow any reasoning about the involved types. Things like `scalar * vector` might have different semantics depending on types and dimensions of the variables in use.

Answer (score 0):

When you add sums of array elements to a `PuLP` model, you have to use built-in `PuLP` constructs like `lpSum` to do it -- you can't just add arrays together (as you discovered).

So your `score` definition should look something like this:

```
score = pulp.lpSum([train['target'][i] - (x * array1[i] + y * array2[i] + z * array3[i]) for i in arr_ind])
```

A few notes about this:

[+] You didn't provide the definition of `roc_auc_score` so I just pretended that it equals the sum of the element-wise difference between the target array and the weighted sum of the other 3 arrays.

[+] I suspect your actual calculation for `roc_auc_score` is nonlinear; more on this below.

[+] `arr_ind` is a list of the indices of the arrays, which I created like this:

```
# build array index
arr_ind = range(len(array1))
```

[+] You also didn't include the arrays, so I created them like this:

```
array1 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
array2 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
array3 = np.random.rand(10, 1)

train = {}
train['target'] = np.ones((10, 1))
```

Here is my complete code, which compiles and executes, though I'm sure it doesn't give you the result you are hoping for, since I just guessed about `target` and `roc_auc_score`:

```
import numpy as np
import pulp

# create the LP object, set up as a maximization problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem('Giapetto', pulp.LpMaximize)

# dummy arrays since arrays weren't in OP code
array1 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
array2 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
array3 = np.random.rand(10, 1)

# build array index
arr_ind = range(len(array1))

# set up decision variables
x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=0)
y = pulp.LpVariable('y', lowBound=0)
z = pulp.LpVariable('z', lowBound=0)

# dummy roc_auc_score since roc_auc_score wasn't in OP code
train = {}
train['target'] = np.ones((10, 1))
score = pulp.lpSum([train['target'][i] - (x * array1[i] + y * array2[i] + z * array3[i]) for i in arr_ind])

prob += score

coef = x + y + z

prob += coef == 1

# solve the LP using the default solver
optimization_result = prob.solve()

# make sure we got an optimal solution
assert optimization_result == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

# display the results
for var in (x, y,z):
    print('Optimal weekly number of {} to produce: {:1.0f}'.format(var.name, var.value()))
```

Output:

```
Optimal weekly number of x to produce: 0
Optimal weekly number of y to produce: 0
Optimal weekly number of z to produce: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now, if your `roc_auc_score` function is nonlinear, you will have additional troubles. I would encourage you to try to formulate the score in a way that is linear, possibly using additional variables (for example, if you want the score to be an absolute value).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am still not getting the solution for my problem, as this is giving coefficient as 1 for one of the three array and 0 for the others, which is not the ideal solution. May be I should formulate my score better.

Comment: Right, most likely you will need a better score function. The problem is that the most natural score functions will be nonlinear, and then you will have to figure out how to to deal with the nonlinearity. However, your question was about using arrays within `PuLP` expressions. If you also have a question about formulating your objective function, it would make sense to post that as a separate question.